# Rephrasing a paragraph using java

Tags: java

Very new java student here (My first post, sorry for wrong formatting). I need help with rephrasing a paragraph.
I need to change the letters of the paragraph to the 13th next letter ie changing a to n and so on meanwhile conserving the structure of the paragraph ie line breaks, full stops, etc...I have only been able to change a word so far and need to expand this code to be able to do it with a paragraph...Thanks in advance...Much appreciated...

```
public class Assignment1b {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please type any word: ");
            String word = s.nextLine();
            String ROT13 = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
                char c = word.charAt(i);
                int value = c - 'a' + 1;
                value = value + 13;
                char ency = (char)((value % 26) + 'a' - 1);
                ROT13 = ROT13 + ency;
            }
            System.out.println("The encrypted word is: " + ROT13);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is a paragraph any different than a word?  Just stick an if statement in there and ignore whitespace characters.  See [`Character#isWhitespace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)).  Or you can go the other way and ignore everything that isn't alphanumeric.

Comment: Thank you very much...I will give it a try....I am super new to Java...First semester student..

Comment: You are encoding the paragraph, not rephrasing it.

Answer (score 1):

1. General good programming practice: one method does one thing, and one thing only.  This makes code easier to read, test, maintain and reuse.  I suggest you start by taking the stuff in your `for ()` loop and sticking it in a new method.  Call it  `private char encryptCharacter(char oldCharacter)`, or some such.  Add the return value to your ROT13 string to build the answer, as you are currently doing.
2. Your problem is now in this secondary module - how to preserve line breaks, spaces and similar characters.  Refer to Charlie Armstrong's comment, that will help you identify them.  You will probably end up with something like:

```
private char encryptCharacter(char oldCharacter) {
  if (isWhiteSpaceOrPunctuation(oldCharacter)) {
    return oldCharacter;
  } else {
    // add your code to encrypt the character here
    return encryptedCharacter;
  }
}

private boolean isWhiteSpaceOrPunctuation(char character) {
  //  return true or false, as appropriate
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million...I will use this in my code and see what happens...I really do appreciate your help...You are guiding me towards the right path...Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split paragraph by words, using method split of String class and passing the char, that splits words, in this case, the space `" "`. This method return array of String (`String[]`), which means, array of words, but I convert it to `List<String>` using `Arrays.asList()` method, to facilitate the process. Next, I iterate this list, and apply the rephrase method, that encript or change each word.

```
    //    this split your paragraph, and invoke your code, which means, rephrase method by word 
    public static String encript(String paragraph){
        //  split words by spaces, but punctuation still
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList(paragraph.split(" ").clone());

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(String word : words) {
            //  rephrase and append
            sb.append(rephrase(word));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    //    this is your code in a method, I recommend you rebuild this method using StringBuilder, it is more efficient
    public static String rephrase(String word){
        String ROT13 = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            int value = c - 'a' + 1;
            value = value + 13;
            char ency = (char)((value % 26) + 'a' - 1);
            ROT13 = ROT13 + ency;
        }

        return ROT13;
    }
```

Comment: Please check out the [answer] link. When answering a question, it is nice to post code and comments in the code, but the answer also should contain text that explains the source of the original poster's and a solution. The code should illustrate the solution but shouldn't be all that is posted. Again, comments in code is nice, but you need text separate from code that explains.

Comment: Understand that unlike a traditional help site, this is a question and answer site where the goal is to have a repository of questions and answers that are helpful to *all*, current question askers *and future visitors with similar problems*. An answer without text is not helpful to this second *and key group*.

Comment: Ok, I added text to explain code.